# How can I append the node ID to the node title while saving a node?

Tags: 7, nodes

When a node is saved, I want to append the NID to the title of the node.

```
$node->title = "XYZ_" . $node->nid;
```

If I put this code inside `hook_node_presave()`, it won't work because NID(`$node->nid`) is not available.

If I put this code inside `hook_node_insert()`, NID (`$node->nid`) is available but still won't work because we can't alter `$node` values inside `hook_node_insert()` as the transaction is already under way.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: There's [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) which lets you use tokens to build a title. Maybe it can do what you want.

Comment: drupal_register_shutdown_function() solved the issue. Thanks.